Using JS to control 360 YouTube Video's Orientation
I want to add buttons to control a 360 YouTube video's orientation (panning left/right, tilting up/down) using HTML and JavaScript. Even though it's not documented in the YouTube iframe SDK, and even dispatching a keydown event on the embedded iframe doesn't work, has anyone found a solution to this?
It could be blocked to be handled by developer without YouTube and Google developers. What do you think?

The docs have an example on how to control a 360 YouTube iframe, might be useful
